# Multiple objects in Javascript

Tags: javascript, oop

I'm having troubles making multiple instances of a class in Javascript. The class is like this:

```
function spider(){
this.step = 3;
this.moveDelay = 12;
this.moving = false;
this.moveInterval = null;
this.movement_list = null;
this.iterator = 0;
this.movement_delay = 500;
this.image = document.getElementById("spider");

this.iterate_movement = function (){
var bx = board.to_block_x(this.getx());
    var by = board.to_block_y(this.gety());

switch(this.movement_list[this.iterator]) {
case "l":
        var pos = {x: bx-1, y: by};
        this.test_and_move(pos);
        break;

    case "d":
        var pos = {x: bx, y: by+1};
        this.test_and_move(pos);
        break;

    case "r":
        var pos = {x: bx+1, y: by};
        this.test_and_move(pos);
        break;

    case "u":
        var pos = {x: bx, y: by-1};
        this.test_and_move(pos);
        break;
    }
if(this.iterator < this.movement_list.length - 1) this.iterator += 1;
else this.iterator = 0;
};

this.animate = function (final_pos) {
    var x = this.getx();
    var y = this.gety();

    var dx = final_pos.x - x;
    var dy = final_pos.y - y;

    this.moving = dx!=0 || dy!=0;

    if (this.moving) {
        if (dx >= this.step)
            this.setx(x+this.step);
        else if (dx <= -this.step)
            this.setx(x-this.step);
        else
            this.setx(final_pos.x);

        if (dy >= this.step)
            this.sety(y+this.step);
        else if (dy <= -this.step)
            this.sety(y-this.step);
        else
            this.sety(final_pos.y);
    }
    else
        window.clearInterval(this.moveInterval);
};

this.setx = function (x, set_layer) {
    this.image.setAttribute("x", +x);
    this.conditioned_set_layer(set_layer);
};

this.sety = function (y, set_layer) {
    this.image.setAttribute("y", +y);
    this.conditioned_set_layer(set_layer);
};

this.set_pos = function (x, y, movement_list, set_layer) {
    this.setx(x, false);
    this.sety(y, false);
this.movement_list = movement_list;
    this.conditioned_set_layer(set_layer);
};

this.getx = function () {
    return +this.image.getAttribute("x");
};

this.gety = function () {
    return +this.image.getAttribute("y");
};

this.get_pos = function () {
    return {
        x: this.getx(),
        y: this.gety(),
    }
};

this.set_layer = function (layer) {
    layer.appendChild(this.image);
};

this.auto_set_layer = function () {        
    var pos = this.get_pos();

    if (board.blocks[pos.x][pos.y].hill)
        this.set_layer(l_hill_entities);
    else
        this.set_layer(l_ground_entities);
};

this.conditioned_set_layer = function (set_layer) {
    if ((set_layer === undefined || set_layer == true) &&
        !this.moving)
            this.auto_set_layer();
};

this.test_and_move = function (pos) {
    if (board.is_inside(pos)) {
    this.moving = true;
        var self = this;

        var move_f = function () {
            self.animate(board.to_board_pos(pos))
        };

        this.moveInterval = window.setInterval(move_f,
            this.moveDelay);

    }
};
};
```

The idea is to instanciate multiple spiders on a game board, but when I do:

```
var spider1 = new spider();
spider1.set_pos(0, 0, ["d"]);
spider1.iterate_movement();
var spider2 = new spider();
spider2.set_pos(0, 0, ["r"]);
spider2.iterate_movement();
```

It should create 2 spiders, and then move the first down and the second one right, but the second object is overwriting the first one, or they just move at the same time because I can see only the last spider.

I know that there must be some global variable in my class, but I've been unable to find it, and I'm new to javascript, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `document.getElementById("spider")` that line alone makes it so that you can only have one. If you had two, how would you get one instances image vs another, if they both have the same id?

Comment: Also don't forget that JavaScript has function scope. You have a lot of `this` that are probably not referencing what you think they are.

Comment: You could use the element as a parameter to the constructor.

Comment: It was the document.getElementById("spider") all along. Thanks to everyone, problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

They are all sharing the image.  You need to create a new image inside the constructor, probably.  You won't be able to reuse the value returned by getElementById.

```
this.image = document.createElement("img");
document.getElementById("spider").parentNode.appendChild(this.image);
```

Comment: You should change `parent` into `parentNode`. :)

Comment: You are right, I changed the image and it completely worked as indended. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @GermanIgnacioOrtegaRodrigue You should accept this answer if it solved your problem by clicking the check mark below the answer's score.